# Inserting JSON objects into mySQL database using node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, reactjs

I am building an application using node.js, express, and mySql, and I have to find a way to insert hundreds of JSON objects into my database. I have to use an INSERT IGNORE statement as the json objects i received from an API contain much more data than I currently need.

My table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE songs (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    artist VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    release_date VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    image_url VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

And my JSON objects look like this:

```
{
    "id": 857276082,
    "readable": true,
    "title": "Da Baby",
    "title_short": "Da Baby",
    "title_version": "",
    "link": "https://www.deezer.com/track/857276082",
    "duration": 128,
    "rank": 339022,
    "explicit_lyrics": true,
    "explicit_content_lyrics": 1,
    "explicit_content_cover": 2,
    "preview": "https://cdns-preview-a.dzcdn.net/stream/c-a80177e5977326333a9b5f7c2f864822-4.mp3",
    "md5_image": "6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be",
    "artist": {
      "id": 14285019,
      "name": "Chiki Wanted",
      "link": "https://www.deezer.com/artist/14285019",
      "picture": "https://api.deezer.com/artist/14285019/image",
      "picture_small": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/artist/cb3ad9821020b6f003e9caae6e97fdfb/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_medium": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/artist/cb3ad9821020b6f003e9caae6e97fdfb/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_big": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/artist/cb3ad9821020b6f003e9caae6e97fdfb/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "picture_xl": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/artist/cb3ad9821020b6f003e9caae6e97fdfb/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "tracklist": "https://api.deezer.com/artist/14285019/top?limit=50",
      "type": "artist"
    },
    "album": {
      "id": 127792882,
      "title": "Da Baby",
      "cover": "https://api.deezer.com/album/127792882/image",
      "cover_small": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be/56x56-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "cover_medium": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be/250x250-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "cover_big": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be/500x500-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "cover_xl": "https://e-cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be/1000x1000-000000-80-0-0.jpg",
      "md5_image": "6e00d1b23d9d30b5c10045bb520668be",
      "tracklist": "https://api.deezer.com/album/127792882/tracks",
      "type": "album"
    },
    "type": "track"
  }
```

How would I be able to set up a function to take each JSON file, deconstruct it, then push it to my MySQL database?

School project btw, i'm very new to using sql and node.js

-edit-

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dbCon  = mysql.createConnection({
   connectionLimit : 50,
   host: 'localhost',
   user: 'replay_music_user',
   password: 'NewApp#1',
   database: 'replay_music',

 });


 dbCon.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO songs (title, artist.name) VALUES ?";

    var json_data = require('./songs9.json')

    var data = JSON.parse(json_data);


    dbCon.query(sql, [data], function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
    });
  });
```

Ive tried to run this in node but i get the error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1" where i try and parse the JSON data.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: uploaded an edit showing my code, hope you can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of `dbCon.query` method must be a query array. In case of multiple entries, the array must be 2D array.

so,

`const sql = "INSERT INTO Table(field1, field 2) VALUES ?"`

`queryArr = [[field1Val, field2Val], [field1Val, field2Val]]`

`dbConn.query(sql, [queryArr]);`

I've fixed this in your code, I don't see release_date in your JSON so make sure to handle this.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var json_data = require('./songs9.json');

var dbCon = mysql.createConnection({
  connectionLimit: 50,
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'replay_music_user',
  password: 'NewApp#1',
  database: 'replay_music',

});

dbCon.connect(function (err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");

  var sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO songs (title, name, release_date, image_url) VALUES ?";

  var data = JSON.parse(json_data);

  const queryArr = [data.map((field) => [field.title, field.artist.name, field.release_date, field.preview])];

  dbCon.query(sql, queryArr, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

please use text type data-type instead of varchar for big amount of data.